# LINQ query with variable in where clause

Tags: linq, c#-4.0

I have been at this for hours, poured over multiple questions that are similar.  What do I do to get this code to work?

```
public void DoSomething(List<TheObj> objs, string lnameStr)
    {
        var pQuery = (from o in objs
                      where o.Lname.Contains(lnameStr)
                      select o).ToList();

        foreach (var theObj in pQuery)
        {
            Trace.WriteLine(theObj.Fname);
        }
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: What error are you getting? What is it supposed to do and what's it actually doing?

Comment: What would be wrong with it now?

Comment: Psychic debugging: there is at least one object in your list that has a `null` `Lname`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public void DoSomething(List<TheObj> objs, string lnameStr)
    {
      if(objs != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(lnameStr))   
       {
        var pQuery = (from o in objs
                      where !string.IsNullOrEmpty(p.Lname) && 
                            o.Lname.Contains(lnameStr)
                      select o).ToList();

        foreach (var theObj in pQuery)
        {
            Trace.WriteLine(theObj.Fname);
        }
      }
    }
```